# Can't get the action.payload go to the state Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

So I'm new to React and Redux Toolkit, I've been trying to get some 'posts' from my localhost API, I do get the payload and it gets displayed in the Redux Dev Tools, nevertheless I can't get this payload to be put on the state.

My postSlice.js :

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";


export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts", async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/post`,
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return err.res.data;
  }
});
const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: {
   posts: [],
   loading: false,
   error:"",
  },
  extrareducers: {
   [getPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
     state.loading = true;
   },
   [getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
     console.log(action.payload);
     state.loading = false;
     state.posts = action.payload;
   },
   [getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
     state.loading = false;
     state.posts = action.payload.message;
   },
 },
 });



export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

Then I use the dispatch on a React Component

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../redux/features/postSlice";
const Thread = () => {
const [loadPost, setLoadPost] = useState(true);
const dispatch= useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadPost ) {
      dispatch(getPosts());
      setLoadPost(false)
    }
  }, [loadPost, dispatch]);

  return <div>Fil d'actualités</div>;
};

export default Thread;
```

Finally I get this on the State in Redux Dev Tool

```
posts(pin):[]
loading(pin): false
error(pin): ""
```

And this on the Action:

```
payload (pin): [{...}{...}{...}]
```

Also, through the pending, fulfilled and rejected states, loading won't change a bit, even if I pass it on true or false directly with VSCode nor the log I put on the fulfilled extra reducer, it's like the action doesn't affect the state at all, therefore I have the another reducer working fine with the async functions, any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: My bad, i made a misspelling mistake, 'r' instead of 'R' in 'extraReducers' declaration, the kind of error you feel so dumb about

Comment: Typo: `extrareducers` should be `extraReducers`. Javascript identifiers are case sensitive. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to close the question, but it was the typo in deed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `extraRedcuer` that way:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(getPosts.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.loading = true;
  }),
  builder.addCase(getPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    console.log(action.payload);
    state.loading = false;
    state.posts = action.payload;
  }),
  builder.addCase(getPosts.rejected, (state, action) => {
    state.loading = false;
    state.posts = action.payload.message;
  }),
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohammed Ahmed ! I've seen actually both ways to set the extraReducers, but you pointed at something it was driving me insane! It was actually the letter 'R' in Reducers!! I spelled 'extrareducers' when it had to be extraReducers!! actually it works fine in both ways, with the builder and with [ ]

Comment: Just FYI, in SO we don't request other users to vote a certain way or accept answers. Voting and accepting is completely optional.